Rails async check for uniqueness
I have a multistage registration for users for a somewhat complicated app. I need to be able to use js to check for unique usernames, etc because users will get pissed off having to redo a multistage form.  What is the simplest way to use js to query ActiveRecord?

What have you done so far?

The simplest way is to have it call a method on a rails controller that performs the query.

I guess the name is included in a form. What you can do is make a form specifically for the name. Add a stimulus controller to it. And make an action input and direct this action to a stimulus method that will submit the form. The form answers turbo_stream that updates a turbo frame with either a ✔ or a ✖

Please note that you will need to use multistage persistence as well for this to work appropriately. e.g. you will have to persist the username as soon as it is entered. You will likely also need a cleanup process to remove usernames when the user did not complete the full registration process.
